# How to express a heavy dependency between two classes as sort of contract for subclassing?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, inheritance, relationship

I don't know how to express the dependency / relation of two classes that both will be subclassed. I think a example could help here:

Say I have two classes, `Master` and `Slave`.
The `Master` class has some methods, like `void use(Slave * s)` and `Slave * generateFrom(int a)`

```
class Master
{
  public:
    virtual void use(Slave * s) = 0;
    virtual Slave * generateFrom(int a) = 0;
};

class Slave
{
};
```

Now I want to subclass both of these classes, but don't want to lose the relation between them:

```
ConcreteMasterA ma();
ConcreteSlaveA * sa = ma.generateFrom(1);
ConcreteMasterB mb();
mb.use(sa); // THIS SHALL NOT WORK


Master * m = new ConcreteMasterA();
Slave * s = m->generateFrom(1); //s should now be a ConcreteSlaveA
m->use(s); // THIS SHALL WORK
```

Is there a way to express this relation with C++ classes / templates / whatever ?

#### Additional information

Perhaps I need to be more specific:

I have the class `Arm` which represents a robot arm. The state of an robot arm is specified by some number of parameters (angles, distances) and shall be represented by the class `JointVariableVector`

I want to control an arm using another class later on, but this class then shall only use methods exported by `Arm` and `JointVariableVector`.

`Arm` will be subclassed to provide the correct functionality per specific robot arm (e.g. SCARA or KUKA) and because of different structures I need subclasses from `JointVariableVector` (eg. one subclass with only 2 angles, and another with 3 angles and one distance)

Comment: Use pointers instead of passing parameters by value.

Comment: @Nick and then use pass-by-reference instead of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
class ConcreteMasterA:public Master
{
    typedef ConcreteSlaveA MySlaveType;
    public:
    virtual void use(Slave * s){
        MySlaveType* ms = dynamic_cast<MySlaveType*>(s);
        assert(ms); // or other type of error handling
    }

    virtual Slave * generateFrom(int a){
        return new MySlaveType();
    }
};
```

If you want a more strict test you could use

```
assert(typeid(s)==typeid(MySlaveType*));
```

in your use function

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable Master in the slave class which contains the Master that created it. When use is called, compare to this value and accept when the values are equal.

```
class Slave {
private:
    Master * creator;

public:
    Slave(Master* master) : creator(Master) {};
    Master * getMaster() { return creator; }
}

class Master {
    Slave *generateForm(int) {
        return new Slave(this);
    }

    void use(Slave) {
        if (Slave.getMaster) == this) {
             do stuff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. Using a member makes it possible to compare whether the same master was used when generating the Slave. What I probably missed to explain is, that it should be possible to do something like `Master * m2 = new ConcreteMasterA(); m2->use(s);` after the code from above. Furthermore I will have to create Slaves that don't "belong" to any master object.

Comment: The second thing is relatively simple: slaves not belonging to a master have their creator set to null when you properly initialize the property. The first is trickier, you could do some bookkeeping in a hash map, but it would make your code pretty complex.